# How can i convert one currency value to another currency value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services

I am new in iPhone application development. Now i am developing iPhone application. In my application i need to use currency conversion. How can i convert one currency value to another currency value. If any one API achieving this please add link, or example code is there add that url, It is very help full for development.

Please help.

Comment: You can use this one : http://motyar.blogspot.in/2011/12/googles-currency-converter-and-json-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use google rest api service which will return a json

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD%3D%3FINR

here converting 1USD to INR

Answer (score 1):

Go to google.com, and search programmable web. It will list all different sort of web services for you and then you may choose one and use it inside your application.

Answer (score 1):

Use free web services to retrieve currency rates. This is the only thing you need, all the rest is math. Here is one [Free, hourly-updated exchange rates](http://openexchangerates.org/documentation/)